# What is the image of the following function?

Tags: functions

So I have this.
$$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
g(x)=2\sin^2x -2\sin x +3$$
What's the function's image $Im(g)$ equals to?

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous its image is an interval. Since it attains both maximum and minimum values its image is a closed interval bounded by those values. You can use elementary algebra and trig to find the max and min.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that $g(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and continuos and  on $[0,2\pi]$ therefore $g(x)$ has a maximum and a minimum on that interval, then consider

$$g(x)=2\sin^2x -2\sin x +3\implies g'(x)=4\sin x \cos x-2 \cos x=2\cos x(2\sin x-1)$$

Comment: well i've done that, but after this, everything become unclear. How do I find the max and the min ?

Comment: @MihaiRobert The points to consider are for $\cos x=0$ $x=\pi/2$ that is a local maximum and $x=3\pi/2$ that is also local maximum and then for $\sin x=1/2$ $x=\pi/6$ that is a local minimum and $x=5\pi/6$ that is also local minimum.

Comment: @MihaiRobert The method indicated by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner seems more effective.

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thank you !

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Write your function in the form
$$2\left(\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=2\left(\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{5}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you maximize and minimize the function using 1st and 2nd derivative of it, then you will find that, the maximum is 7 and the minimum is $\dfrac{5}{2}$. And as it is a continuous periodic function,so it's value varies from $\dfrac{5}{2}$ to $7$.

so the image of the function is [$\dfrac{5}{2},7$].